# how to validate field against multiple regex in laravel

Tags: regex, laravel

i wants to validate video_url field againts two regex. if video_url match to any regex than it should be passed and validate it.

```
here is these two regex.
/https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=.+/
/https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/.+/
```

im trying following way to validate video_url field

```
 'video_url'   =>   array('regex:/((https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=.+)|(https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/.+))/')
```

but it validate failed and said video_url url is not correct format.
im trying to validate following two urls

```
1 . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_DSCLqgZCo
2.  https://www.youtube.com/embed/U_DSCLqgZCo
```

Comment: can you include the laravel validation script. also what's your laravel version

Comment: im using laravel 5.2, laravel validation script is already mentioned in question. it here
'video_url'   =>   array('regex:/((https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=.+)|(https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/.+))/')